# Unable to run ionic3 application

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I have an ionic3 application and I installed ionic with `npm install -g ionic cordova` , but when I run the application with `ionic serve`, i get this error :

```
typescript error

[app-scripts]             Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.

[app-scripts]             Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.

[app-scripts] [11:58:10]  typescript error
[app-scripts] [11:58:10]  ionic-app-script task: "serve"
[app-scripts] [11:58:10]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
[app-scripts] TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
[app-scripts]     at Object.escapeHtml 

 [ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

this is the package.json

```
   "scripts": {
   "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
   "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
   "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  }
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
   "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.9.2",
   "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.11.0",
   "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.10.0",
   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.9.2",
   "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.9.2",
   "@ionic/core": "^4.0.0-beta.12",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
   "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular": "^1.7.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
   "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
   "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
   "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
   "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
   "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
   "ionic": "^4.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
   "ionicons": "3.0.0",
   "rxjs": "5.5.11",
   "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
   "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  }
```

What is the problem ? In that because I m using ionic4 to run an ionic3 application ? and haw can I fix that ?

Comment: Can you update your question with scripts attribute of package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please delete your node modules folder

**Install latest app script from below command:**

> npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

**Now install Node modules by below command:**

> npm install

Try now, it will help you.

Comment: You save me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running follows,

`npm uninstall @ionic/app-scripts --save-dev`

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

After that run `ionic serve`

Comment: It is always the same error, when I try to run the application with ' cordova run ' it works but I can't understand why it doesn't run with ' ionic serve '