# Ionic app script has unexpectedly closed (exit code 0)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
F:\Familybook\trunk\FabAppLatest> ionic info
√ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 28 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

***the above information is about ionic, Cordova and my system information. I'm facing the exit 0 error while CLI serving the app script. I attached my error statement below***

```
F:\Familybook\trunk\FabAppLatest> ionic serve
> ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser
[app-scripts] [13:13:35]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 0).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802750/8850397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take care about using Ionic CLI 4 for ionic 3 framework projects. Try with Ionic Cli 3.20.0

```
npm install -g ionic@3.20.0
```

I had problems with Ionic cli 4 on my Ionic 3 project. And whenever you build the app it suggests you to update CLI

Comment: No matching version found for ionic-cli@3.20.0  (I am facing this error while executing your command)

Comment: But now I'm facing another error    (app-scripts serve unexpectedly failed.settings: undefinedcontext: [object Object])

Comment: I also tried this command(npm run ionic:serve) but it was not working

Answer (score 1):

For me, below commands helped to resolve the above specified issue:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Please find more details here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3368

Comment: I solved above error after the re-installation of each and every component in my system

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your **node modules** folder

Install latest **app script** from following command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Now **install Node modules** from following command:

```
 npm install
```

Try now, it will help you.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802107/unable-to-run-ionic3-application)

Answer (score 0):

After searching all morning I decided to set up a new Ionic 3 environment to had the same error but with a new prompt info after running **ionic serve**:

> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
>   [ng] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
>   [ng]     at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>   [ng]     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

So, in my case for some reason when I worked with Ionic 1 deleted the /etc/hosts content, then I solve the problem restoring a new /etc/hosts archive with default lines info.